# swt control on text fields

Tags: java, swt, controls

I have a few text fields on my gui. My job is to calculate  number of text fields that have been entered by the gui user. So how can I get control on these text fields which have been entered into my swt code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to know the no. of Text fields where user entered some text?

Comment: Yes niranjan exactly...I mean the number of text fields